# How to specify immediate width?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86

Imagine I want to jump using an immediate (hidden behind a macro):

```
jmp label
```

How do I specify the width of the immediate so for example the `jmp` instruction for **rel8** is executed. I tried:

```
jmp byte label
```

But it doesn't work. I'm working with the MSVC inline assembler.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't get to decide. If you're lucky, you can *force* large jumps.

Answer (score 2):

The assembler will automatically choose the smallest encoding for the jump instruction. With MASM you can override this with `jmp SHORT label`, but the Microsoft inline assembler ignores the SHORT keyword.

Note that even with MASM, when using the SHORT keyword the label has to be defined somewhere else in the assembly file and be within –128 to +127 bytes of the jump instruction. Otherwise you'll get an error.